# C# Bootstrap Navbar not responding

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap-4

I tried to find a solution to my problem but none matches my exact case.

My problem is the following: I am trying to add the Bootstrap 4 Navbar to my Page, which works fine - it's showing up. But it doesn't have any click events, I can't click the buttons or write something in the search field.

I tried to load the jQuery before loading the bootstrap.css file but it didn't work either.

This is the loading order in my Site.Master:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/umd/popper.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script src="/epadoc_Framework/EHR/Scripts/js/FontSize.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/global.js"></script>

<script src="/epadoc_Framework/EHR/Scripts/pk_script.js"></script>

<link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

It's the right Bootstrap version aswell.
Here is some default navbar to test if its working (it's just copied from Bootstrap):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

And that is what it looks like in the header of the page:

[image: Navbar]

As you can see it's showing up normally, but I just can't interact with it, I don't even get the hover effect when I mouseover the bar.

Any ideas what is going wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried to place ``<link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>`` before the scripts. What kind of document is this 'HTML'?

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the `.css` in the head of the document like so.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
//Your content

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/umd/popper.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script src="/epadoc_Framework/EHR/Scripts/js/FontSize.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/global.js"></script>

<script src="/epadoc_Framework/EHR/Scripts/pk_script.js"></script>
</body>
```